# using the result of a query in an other query

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a problem and I hope you can help me.
I have to use the result of a query in an other in the same button, when I execute this code I have: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{             
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    //use a sqlparameter to avoid the possibility of sql injection
    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("p1", ddlClients.SelectedValue);
    SqlParameter q = new SqlParameter("q1", ddlProjets.SelectedValue);
    SqlParameter t = new SqlParameter("t1", ddlProduits.SelectedValue);
    SqlParameter r = new SqlParameter("r1", ddlShift.SelectedValue);
    SqlParameter s = new SqlParameter("s1", ddlDefaut.SelectedValue);


    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(q);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(r);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(s);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(t);


    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Aff (Operations_ID, Emplacements_ID, Projets_ID, Zones_ID, Machines_ID )values(15, 25, @p1, 1, 5)";

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Aff')";
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Insp (Affectations_ID, Shifts_ID, Produits_ID, date,  Machine) values(reader ,@r1, @t1, '" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "')"; // here is the problem
    }

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Insp')";
    SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader2.Read())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into def (BaseDefauts_ID, Inspection_ID,   matricule, quantite) values(@s1, reader2, '" + TextBox3.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "')";
    }  

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Cascad.aspx");
}
```

Comment: cant you just use join ?, that way you can join the new "query" within the results of the first one...

Comment: IMO you may refactor to do everything in one query (and using parameters instead of SQL concatenation)...anyway...SqlDataReader MUST be disposed after each use (and same for connection).

Comment: notice setting the CommandText back to back won't work. The first sql will be replaced by the latter. You would need to either execute the first one, or combine them into a single command text.

Comment: Never use GUI value directly in queries. Makes your code vulnerable for code injection.

Comment: I do this but I still have problem, it doesn't recognize "reader" inside of the insert command
using (SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Aff')", con))
     {using (SqlDataReader reader = cmmd.ExecuteReader())
               { if (reader.Read())
                   { SqlParameter r = new SqlParameter("r1", ddlShift.SelectedValue);
               cmmd.Parameters.Add(r);
               cmmd.CommandText = "insert into Insp (Affectations_ID, Shifts_ID, Produits_ID, date,  Machine) values(reader ,@r1, '" + TextBox1.Text + "')";
           }
               cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();}

Answer (score 0):

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

You need to dispose the data reader, e.g.:

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   if (reader.Read())
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

exiting out of the `using` block will cause the data reader to be disposed, and you can do `ExecuteReader` again.

Comment: when I use                                                                                               using( SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               if (reader.Read())
               {
                   cmd.CommandText = "insert into Insp (Affectations_ID, Shifts_ID, Produits_ID, date,  Machine) values(reader ,@r1, @t1, '" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "')";
                  
               }
           }     I get Invalid column name 'reader2'.

Comment: @Lamyae apparently, you've made it past the previous error, and you clearly have another issue you'll need to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Type `reader.Close();` before `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Insp')";` in your code.

Comment: PLZ I have an other problem when I execut ,it doesn't recognize the variable "reader" :Must declare the scalar variable "@reader"